# Is Laplace always the superior way to solve an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I recently learned how to use Laplace transforms and inverse Laplace transforms to solve ODE and it seems to give much easier solutions than the traditional way of solving differentials. Are all ODE solveable with Laplace and is it always the best method or is it just like everything else in math, sometimes method x is better and sometimes method y is better?

Comment: Short answer: No. And remember that Laplace transform works mainly for *linear* differential equations.

Comment: Among other things,  you can only solve using Laplace if you have all the initial values of the function up to the n-1 derivative.  Sometimes you have other values, like boundary conditions.  However, in situations where it is applicable, it transforms calculus problems into algebra problems, which are usually nicer.

Comment: Laplace transforms are very good when you have a nice list of transformed functions and their inverse transforms. At that point, why not simply have a nice list of solutions to differential equations? Is it easier to memorize something, or to memorize a trick for deriving something in real time? You will constantly ask yourself this question in any STEM field, and the answer will always depend on the situation.

Comment: Simple example: I used to derive the angle addition formula from the product-to-sum rule for complex exponentiation when I needed it. Eventually, this became too time consuming for something that's really not so hard to memorize, so instead I just memorized the angle addition formula. Sometimes it will be easier to solve an ODE by inspection because you've memorized a similar solution. Sometimes it will be easier to solve with Laplace because you've memorized some transforms. Sometimes it will be easier with yet a different method.